# jQuery image slider in html website loads all images at once for a moment

Tags: jquery, html, image

I have a jQuery image slider on the header section of my website that displays images periodically in an automated sliding motion. Now the problem is when you load the page for the 1st time(nothing is cached), it loads all the images in the slider at once and it aligns the images one on top of the other on the webpage(one div on top of another), so you see all the images at once the moment the page loads. My website: www.mrsinghcafe.com/league/

HTML

```
<div id="menu">
    <a href="javascript:void(0);"><img src="img/image-1.jpg" title="Lorem ipsum dolor sitamet conse ctetu" alt="image1" /></a>
    <a href="javascript:void(0);"><img src="img/image-2.jpg" title="Sed do eiusmod tempor incididun" alt="image2" /></a>
    <a href="javascript:void(0);"><img src="img/image-3.jpg" title="Duis aute irure dolor in reprehenderit" alt="image3"/></a>
    <a href="javascript:void(0);"><img src="img/image-4.jpg" title="Voluptate veldolor sit amet conse ctetu" alt="image4" /></a>
    <a href="javascript:void(0);"><img src="img/image-5.jpg" title="Ipsum dolor sit amet conse ctetu" alt="image5" /></a>
</div>
```

I am using this carousel http://dev7studios.com/plugins/caroufredsel/

Comment: please show your code

Comment: can adjust with css. If slider hides/shows images, only display first one using css, hide the rest. Or set overflow, or whatever best suits your situation

Comment: i new to designing can you tell me what part of code you want...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The images aren't hidden with CSS, so they WILL show until JS kicks in on page load.

You could position all the elements in the same place, which is what the carousel plugin is doing.

```
'position: absolute; z-index: 0; display: block;'
```

So in style.css you would add

```
#menu{
    position:relative; /* this constrains any child elements whose position is absolute */
}

#menu a{
    position:absolute;
    top:0;
    left:0;
}
```

Comment: i can provide my index file or css file if any one require...please let me know how  and where to send

Comment: already looked at your code and updated the answer to enable you to add it to your code. You are supposed to post the relevant HTML, at least, in the question.

Comment: hey popnoodles i am sorry i am new to this site and dont know how to operate properly can send you the files if you want..

Comment: +1 for putting in the effort popnoodles. @user3140093 - please don't post questions describing its urgency. Your deadline is not SO's problem.

Comment: Dont send files .Instead create a fiddle at http://jsfiddle.net. There you can also add external files like `CSS,JS...`

Comment: hey krishna i know its not so imp but thanks for the comment will keep it mind ....thanks everyone...

Comment: hi jsfiddle thanks for your kind help in providing me info on how to use this site...thanks..